# Why won't typescript infer my second type argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm trying to set up a type for a generic function. The second type argument should be inferred from the type of the second function argument.

It's not working, though, I think because of the way the type of the second argument also depends on the first type argument...

It's hopefully much easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve by looking at the code:

```js
export type TypedContract = Contract & {
  functions: Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>;
  filters: Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>;
};

export const useTypedRead = <
  C extends TypedContract,
  MethodName extends keyof C["functions"]
>(
  address: string,
  method: MethodName,
  params: Parameters<C["functions"][MethodName]>
): void => {
  /** */
};

// When calling like this, I get "Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1"
useTypedRead<Erc20>("0xSomeAddress", "balanceOf");
```

[Typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqzgBMDCEB2MUAhgMbwC8cA3gFBxwBmArvuQJYEDOAXHAErBS0LAB4uRdvgDmAGjgAKAHQriUabzjF8iANoBdAJRwKAPi07TAbnpN2AGxjAomwcKhiJUKXMUqlahp82npGJuYh1rQAvja0oJCwcML4EnDMXMAYKFiCxFgmcKK2OHCgTvhYXOiYuAREZDCytgCywDAAFhBYAHLEALao5cCV1QDWwIgQjHA4ugBELGwwnKnz+rSmCrb5WFDAXJpePs0Mg53dfG0XvQPAp3BgagOaAArP585conOLrBzcda6a5dW6DfSmWiGPgANwg7AKZhotgA9AAqNFwNEomJxKROKCMMioACi-BwACYAAxlEAVKo1HJ4QgkcjIhiMBwEzTUWK2JYA1J8OgMBgAI2I9m0pGAAHlGAoAPoQADu+GcfGOMmhcFeUAg-XYmVEui10n0cAAZDQ4BKpWxgJrJDI4NEogw+dFaLQUSi4AB1DojZKS+w+OBhiYIDpG+QASTg0nacHmJPAQicBQpCEwWnUzEGhC48jFzHg0gg8AAjPNaBksrU8mIyZSqVt5lSQABlA3AACCWD2By483k8zt0rljHmhjivvQMeqWAgBzgKo6xHgCYSGcU+OA9jDmVSqAIcEyKQKgUMJbL0eDy4O+AA5PBQ6q4D6-YMEBB0pl7xzFA4GmQCnhIfpqkYaBAM6dgPDzaQCxGGAlFoFI0nrf1oDGHxsmwJtCh+Wl6WqfC6hZRoth2Qd9kOJ1vBkB5zlBPgJimGZfgFFZAQ2HU4QRcJ2TgdFMWxXFvSwnC8MbYB8lEFtqXbTse0GAch0OUcUwnB15RnGwgA)

Comment: can you please provide type `Contract` (or just a mock version of it) so I can test it?

Comment: @BorisTB - tbh you can probably remove the intersection with `Contract` entirely

Comment: Reusing one identifier, `Contract`, in two different yet related contexts (type and generic, `TypedContract` extends `Contract` type, but `Contract` generic extends `TypedContract`) looks like a great source of confusion for anyone reading this code a week from now.

Comment: @mbojko - yes, very good point, will certainly change that name.

Comment: @BorisTB added a TS playground link that you can test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use default value for next generics like this:

```js
export const useTypedRead = <
  C extends TypedContract,
  MethodName extends keyof C["functions"] = keyof C["functions"]
>(
  address: string,
  method: MethodName extends keyof C["functions"] ? MethodName : never,
  params: Parameters<C["functions"][MethodName]>
): void => {
  /** */
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#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-IAJJwaTtODzMXgIROApShCYLTqZiDQhceRm5jwaQQeAARnmtAyWVqeTEEulMpO8xlIAAygHgABBLAXK5cebyeax612xgnuALLhYK9GOI59DV6pYCBXOAujrEeD1hLtoogrAPYpaZKkqAEHAmQpAUgSGMOo5VkW75XPgADk8Alq6cDZrmMIwBA6SZMh3YoHA-ydKgaIkP01SMNApGdOwHi9tI-YjDASi0CkaRznm0BjD4yq5MA+SFAS8rfNUImqg05AnGcB6XNcibeDIKKPFCfB-DsgL7MSIK0vSjLMuYdAMJy3K8vyWb8YJwkLmJS6SrKa4btugz7oe1zXmeloXva8yGDYQA)

Comment: ahh, that's it. Can see that a default would be required if you didn't supply a value for the second argument, but not if you do...

Comment: Is there any way to get the intellisense for the `method` argument working?

Comment: @Ed_ good point, I update my answer so it validates method arg

Answer (score 1):

If you could also pass the contract object, typescript could infer it all for you. Like so:

```
export type TypedContract = {
  functions: Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>;
  filters: Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>;
};

export const useTypedRead = <
  Contract extends TypedContract,
  MethodName extends keyof Contract["functions"]
>(
  contract: Contract,
  address: string,
  method: MethodName,
  ...params: Parameters<Contract["functions"][MethodName]>
): void => {
  /** */
};

const myContract = {
  functions: {
    balanceOf: (foo: string, bar: string) => void (0)
  },
  filters: {
    foo: () => void (0)
  }
}

//this doesn't work
useTypedRead(myContract, "0xSomeAddress", "someFunction");

//this works as expected and we have to pass the two parameters
useTypedRead(myContract, "0xSomeAddress", "balanceOf", "foo", "bar");
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqzgBMDCEB2MUAhgMbwC8cA3gLABQccAZgK77kCWBAzgFxwASsFLQsAHh5FO%20AOYAaOAAoAdGuJRZ-OMXyIA2gF0AlHAoA%20HXvMBuBk2acANjGBRtw0VAlSoMhcpqKhpaAroGJmaW4bYMAL529AygkLBwovhScKw8wBgoWMLEWGZw4vZweIQk5HCgrvhYPOiYuAREZDDyFQCywDAAFhBYAHLEALao9cCNzQDWwIgQzJXtNTD6AERsHDDcmZuGDOZKFRkd5AJVF10VxVhQwDzavv7djHCTg8MCfd%20jE2A7yYQTAGgm2gACuCvm4eOJrustjsuLxDvo-kMAZNDOYGMYBAA3CCcEoWGgVAD0ACpqXBqZT4okGBksuNEIjOqU6B8UXteAIeUwmAAjYhOXSkYAAeWYAiUzAgEAErzkijFUBV0jkpnJxNJygADMYKnFgSxnK53IKKg4lfLdZZ9SUlMbTfEGAxKZTBpxmlgIE98AByeAAd2gcwYOTyrSKWCU7M55EUm0NIAAyhBJgBBLAPJ48TapnjZ4AAMXYqPwm2MzPo3t9zQjUDmzWIzRSIlcJV0JTDqAGxEJqBgEDgYOeCAGo4jE5h-Th0dy%20Ww8cTHLWnVT6azufzj2exbgmzFEo4MuYx%202SuvGtrNiAA)